# Windows 8 ISO Mounting at startup / permanently

Tags: mount, iso-image, windows-8

I am using Windows 8 Pro RTM.
It now has the support of mounting ISO files as a system drive, but when the computer is restarted, the ISOs are not mounted anymore.

How can I make this mount permanent (either through a Windows option or a batch script)?

Comment: Why not extract the ISO to a partition or convert it to a VHD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you want an ISO file to be mounted each time you Logon to your PC. You have two methods to do this:

1. Open run and type in `shell:startup`, this will open up the Startup Folder. Place a shortcut to ISO here, and This will work.
2. (**Better Option**) Execute this in Admin CMD

> reg add
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v
>   "Mount ISO" /d "{location to ISO}"

This should work.

Comment: hi, Why is the registry option "better"? thx

Comment: Hi,
On Windows 10, this opens an explorer window at startup with the mounded ISO. Is there a way to silently mount (i.e. without opening explorer) without using registry keys?